# Calling method from AbstractClass<T> handling an instance of AbstractClass

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Let's say I have an abstract class like:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public object GetValue(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from object");
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

Also, I have another abstract class that extends `MyAbstractClass`:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> : MyAbstractClass
{
    public T GetValue(T parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from generics");
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

And a simple concrete class using `string` as the generic type parameter:

```
class MyImpClass : MyAbstractClass<string> { }
```

Now, I'm declaring a list of `MyAbstractClass` (without the generic type), adding an instance of `MyImpClass` and calling your `GetValue` method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<MyAbstractClass> list = new List<MyAbstractClass>();
    list.Add(new MyImpClass());
    list[0].GetValue("Testing...");
}
```

Currently the method from `MyAbstractClass` (without the generic type parameter) is called and `"Hello from object"` is printed out.

If I call the method directly from an instance of `MyImpClass` the method from `MyAbstractClass<T>` is called instead.

```
new MyImpClass().GetValue("Testing...");
```

I'm doing this because in some parts of my application I need receive an instance of `MyAbstractClass<T>` regardless of the generic type parameter. So I'm doing this using `MyAbstractClass`.

My question is: is there a way to call the method from `MyAbstractClass<T>` iterating over a list of `MyAbstractClass`?

I hope I have been clear enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `public object GetValue(object parameter)` `virtual`, and override it in the generic version.

Like this:

```
abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    public virtual object GetValue(object parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from object");
        return parameter;
    }
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> : MyAbstractClass
{
    override public object GetValue(object parameter)
    {
        return GetValue((T)parameter);
    }

    public T GetValue(T parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from generics");
        return parameter;
    }
}

class MyImpClass : MyAbstractClass<string> { }
```

This code:

```
void Main()
{
        IList<MyAbstractClass> list = new List<MyAbstractClass>();
        list.Add(new MyImpClass());
        list[0].GetValue("Testing...");
}
```

Now produces the following output:

> Hello from generics

---

I'm not sure how some people think that this isn't answering the question.

If you remove the `abstract` modifier from all the classes, and use this code:

```
IList<MyAbstractClass> list = new List<MyAbstractClass>();
list.Add(new MyAbstractClass());
list.Add(new MyImpClass());
foreach (var item in list)
{
    item.GetValue("Testing...");
}
```

It produces this output:

> Hello from object
>   Hello from generics

Which seems to be what the OP ultimately wants the code to do; iterate over a collection of the base type, calling the generic method if the instance is generic.

Specifically interpreting the question as requiring that the generic version of the method be the one directly called, seems like ignoring an X / Y Problem to me.

Comment: just realized, return types are not same

Comment: You can't override when the signature isn't the same.

Comment: You will need 2 methods on the subclass, one of the generic type, the other being the override that wraps the generic version. I'll get you an example.

Comment: @BradleyUffner The OP already has two methods.  The wrong method is called.  You've literally just described the code that the OP has in their own question.

Comment: correct, then you have to state that in your answer.

Comment: @Servy No, I'm talking about a separate method that *wraps* the generic version.

Comment: @BradleyUffner And the OP is specifically asking how to have the calling code call the generic version not the non-generic version.  Changing the implementation of the non-generic version wouldn't change the fact that that's what you'd be calling.

Comment: @Servy Except my code seems to be working and producing the exact output the OP is requesting.  If there is some problem with it that I'm not seeing, please let me know.

Comment: @BradleyUffner The code isn't doing what the OP asked for.  They asked for the generic method to be the method called.  You're not calling the generic method, you're calling the non-generic method.  The OP didn't ask how to make the non-generic method print "calling the generic method" when called.

Comment: @Servy That's a very pedantic way of interpreting the question.  The generic version IS getting called in my code, it just passes through  the non-generic version first.

Comment: @Servy - Question says *My question is: is there a way to call the method from MyAbstractClass<T> iterating over a list of MyAbstractClass?* - a way to make it call the generic - doesn't matter what else is called

Comment: @BradleyUffner Unfortunately when I tried to apply this solution to my whole code base I noticed that this does not work for methods that does not have parameters. I reproduced this scenario in this [rextester](http://rextester.com/HIDNT21647). This gives me the error `already defines a member called 'GetValue' with the same parameter types` when I override the method `public virtual object GetValue()`. You know a solution for this scenario?

Comment: @BrunoPeres Unfortunately, the only way for the compiler to differentiate method overloads is by the method signature.  For methods with no arguments, there really isn't much for the resolver to go on, and this method fails.  At that point, I think the Interface pattern that [Peit suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46647901/526724) is the only way that will work.

Answer (score 4):

To call the generic call directly you need to cast it:

```
(list[0] as MyAbstractClass<string>)?.GetValue("Testing...");
```

But in my opinion this is not a nice solution and you should go with the following:

- In your generic class override the `GetValue` of the non generic base
  and in it call the generic `GetValue`:

  ```
  abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> : MyAbstractClass
  {
      public T GetValue(T parameter)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello from generics");
          return parameter;
      }

      public override object GetValue(object parameter)
      {
          return GetValue((T)parameter);
      }
  }
  ```
- Or, [since C# 6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members), you can write it also like this:

  ```
  public override object GetValue(object parameter) => GetValue((T)parameter);
  ```

You will also need to change the `MyAbstractClass`'s method to virtual:

```
public virtual object GetValue(object parameter)
```

Comment: Your answer is basically the same as mine, it works, and does exactly what the OP is asking about.  I'm not sure what the fuss is about on my answer. I don't see how this *doesn't* answer the question.

Comment: @BradleyUffner - Agree... At first your answer was missing IMO and that is why I posted mine. As for what is actually being asked - I think that it is not really about calling the generic or non-generic of the derived (*My question is: is there a way to call the method from MyAbstractClass<T> iterating over a list of MyAbstractClass?*....) but to actually make it work...

Comment: @GiladGreenThanks for your answer. It helped me to solve this specific case. But unfortunately when I tried to apply this solution to my whole code base I noticed that this does not work for methods that does not have parameters. I reproduced this scenario in this [rextester](http://rextester.com/HIDNT21647). This gives me the error `already defines a member called 'GetValue' with the same parameter types` when I override the method `public virtual object GetValue()`. You know a solution for this scenario?

Comment: @BrunoPeres - It cannot be done in this way. You can use interfaces instead but what you are now asking is actually a different question than the one posted...

Answer (score 2):

What you want to achieve is not possible in this way. This would require you to *override* the method, but what you do is adding a second method which is called *overloading*.

By specification you can neither change the return type of a method nor the parameter type. Other languages support what is called co-variant return types or contra-variant parameter types but C# does not.

What you could do is using interfaces and explicit implementations:

```
interface IInterface
{
    object GetValue(object parameter);
}

abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> : IInterface where T : class
{
    public T GetValue(T parameter)
    {
        // ...
    }

    object IInterface.GetValue(object parameter) => GetValue(parameter as T);
}
```

...and then using the interface:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IList<IInterface> list = new List<IInterface>();
    list.Add(new MyImpClass());
    list[0].GetValue("Testing...");
}
```

Comment: I don't see why using interface is preferred over abstract class, though question may not sharing whole scenario so OP may actually need class not interface

Comment: It does compile theoretically, because I added "where T : class". It does not compile because I am not returning anything. I did also not say that it's better to use interfaces. The other solutions are of course viable as well.

Comment: It seems to me that using an interface is a requirement here.  Doing an abstract class that overloads an abstract class that is implemented....ohh the headache is already starting.  Interface lets you change the implementation (which is your requirement) without all this funky stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Just make your base method virtual and override it in the generic class.

```
  abstract class MyAbstractClass
    {
        public virtual object GetValue(object parameter)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from object");
            return parameter;
        }
    }

abstract class MyAbstractClass<T> : MyAbstractClass
{
 public override object GetValue(object parameter)
    {
        return GetValue((T)parameter);
    }
    public T GetValue(T parameter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from generics");
        return parameter;
    }
}
```